# variadic template for sorting variable number of arrays

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am trying to write a program to sort unsorted 'n' vectors using variadic templates into one sorted vector. It can be done in other ways but I want to do it this way to better my understanding of variadic templates. I don't know if I can achieve that but below is my attempt at it which is not working.

My understanding is that ultimately sorted_n_vector will be reduced to `MergeVector<int> + MergeVector<int> + MergeVectorMergeVector<int>` same as line 50(MergeVector a8(a5 + a6 + a7)) but I think it is wrong. Please help and also give me some code review comments as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

template<typename t>
class MergeVector {
        public:
        std::vector<t> arr_;

        MergeVector(std::vector<t> arr) : arr_(arr) {}

        auto operator + (MergeVector<t> &obj) {
                std::vector<t> dst;
                std::sort(arr_.begin(), arr_.end());
                std::sort(obj.arr_.begin(), obj.arr_.end());
                std::merge(arr_.begin(), arr_.end(), obj.arr_.begin(), obj.arr_.end(), std::back_inserter(dst));
                MergeVector res(dst);
                return res;
        }

        friend auto& operator<<(std::ostream &os, MergeVector<t>& mv)
        {
                std::copy(mv.arr_.begin(), mv.arr_.end(), std::ostream_iterator<t>(os, " "));
                return os;
        }
};

template<typename t>
auto sorted_n_vector(t vec)
{
        return vec;
}

template<typename t, typename... vectors>
auto sorted_n_vector(t vec, vectors... args)
{
        return vec + sorted_n_vector(args...);
}

int main() {
        std::vector<int> a1 = {1, 2, 3};
        std::vector<int> a2 = {4, 5, 6};
        std::vector<int> a3 = {7, 8, 9};
        MergeVector<int> a5(a1);
        MergeVector<int> a6(a2);
        MergeVector<int> a7(a3);
        MergeVector<int> a8(a5 + a6 + a7); //---- Line 50
        std::cout << a8 << std::endl;

#if 1
        MergeVector<int> a9(sorted_n_vector(a5, a6, a7));
        std::cout << a9 << std::endl;
#endif

        return 0;
}
```

I am getting below error:

```
test.cpp:40:20: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('MergeVector<int>' and 'MergeVector<int>')
        return vec + sorted_n_vector(args...);
               ~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:40:22: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'sorted_n_vector<MergeVector<int>, MergeVector<int> >' requested here
        return vec + sorted_n_vector(args...);
                     ^
test.cpp:54:22: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'sorted_n_vector<MergeVector<int>, MergeVector<int>, MergeVector<int> >' requested here
        MergeVector<int> a9(sorted_n_vector(a5, a6, a7));
                            ^
test.cpp:15:7: note: candidate function not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
        auto operator + (MergeVector<t> &obj) {
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want, and what you're getting? If the goal is to just sort a variable amount of `vector`, then a `for` loop over a `vector<vector>` would do the trick. Code review comments are better left to Code Review once you have the program working.

Comment: @WeaktoEnumaElish: Updated the post to answer your questions.

Comment: I really don't understand why -1 without any reason?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I understand what you're doing a lot better now. I can't tell which line of code is #50 though. When you're dealing with a specific line of code not working, it's best to write a comment on it so that we can see.

Comment: @WeaktoEnumaElish: Why -1 though?

Comment: Because it was unclear - "unclear" is one reason that appears if you hover over the downvote button. It also sounded like a question that was better answered by using a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sorted_n_vector` has a return type specified as `auto`, therefore it will return a temporary object, not a reference to some other object.

The you try to call the `operator+` with this temporary as argument, but `operator+` expects a non-const (lvalue) reference parameter.

Binding temporaries (or rather rvalue expressions) to non-const (lvalue) references is forbidden, therefore the compiler will not consider calling your `operator+` and will instead search somewhere else.

Not finding any alternative call for `+`, it gives you the error message you are seeing.

The solution is to take the parameter of `operator+` as const reference:

```
auto operator + (const MergeVector<t> &obj) {
```

Binding temporaries (rvalue expressions) to const (lvalue) references is allowed and works as one would expect.

Edit:

However this will raise another error, because your `operator+` is actually modifying `obj` and `this`. While you can solve this by taking the argument by-value rather than by-reference, that is an unusual design. Typically `+` is expected to not modify its arguments. It would be surprising if `c = a+b` fails because `a` or `b` are not allowed to be modified. You can achieve this by doing the sorting in your `MergeVector` constructor:

```
MergeVector(std::vector<t> arr) : arr_(arr) {
    std::sort(arr_.begin(), arr_.end());
}
```

Then you can drop the `std::sort` lines in `operator+` and you can make it completely `const` in both arguments:

```
auto operator + (const MergeVector<t> &obj) const {
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea declare the `operator+()` as member function. It's good for `operator+=()` but `operator+()` is better for as a `friend` function.

By example

```
    friend auto operator+ (MergeVector<t> mv1, MergeVector<t> mv2)
     {
       std::vector<t> dst;
       std::sort(mv1.arr_.begin(), mv1.arr_.end());
       std::sort(mv2.arr_.begin(), mv2.arr_.end());

       std::merge(std::make_move_iterator(mv1.arr_.begin()),
                  std::make_move_iterator(mv1.arr_.end()),
                  std::make_move_iterator(mv2.arr_.begin()),
                  std::make_move_iterator(mv2.arr_.end()),
                  std::back_inserter(dst));

       return MergeVector<t>{dst};
     }
```

Observe that, now that you pass argument(s) by value (to avoid the compiler error, as explained by uneven_mark), you can use move semantics (see the use of `std::make_move_iterator`).

I know that in your example you use only integers and that for so simple type move semantics isn't useful. But if write template code, you should try to imagine more complex use case.

Bonus suggestion: given that you pass the array by value in your constructor, you should use move semantics in it

```
    MergeVector (std::vector<t> arr) : arr_{std::move(arr)} {}
```

Bonus observation: if you can use C++17, you can use template folding, so

```
template<typename... vectors>
auto sorted_n_vector(vectors... args)
{
   return (args + ...);
}
```